# ExtAudioFile - how to set meta data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, extaudiofile

I am writing audio content to a **m4a** file with **ExtAudioFileWriteAsync** and it is working perfectly. However, I would also like to add meta data to the exported file.

Is this at all possible? If so, how?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can with ExtAudioFile, but maybe with AudioFile's `kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary`.

Comment: No, doesn't work like that, I simply cannot set that property, it throws me an error saying "The operation couldn't be completed."

Comment: I think that leaves only AVAssetExportSession

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much for your feedback and idea, I'll do it with AVAssetExportSession, no way around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it with AVAssetExportSession, loaded the file I am trying to edit into an AVURLAsset, adding the metadata to the export session, then saving the export.

Comment: Another 22 hours and I can :) there is a limitation for accepting your own answer.